# Set unique primary key based on foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I have a model defined as -

```
class sales_order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey()
    item=models.ForeignKey()
    branch=models.ForeignKey()
    ---
    ---other fields
```

Now for each branch, I want to start the primary key from 1 ("id" for eg.), but the default functionality of Django will increment the id irrespective of any other data.

I'm ok even if id keeps on incrementing as it does, and then I set my own field making it unique per branch and this field should auto increment without the user passing the data by checking the previous value from the database such as -

```
class order_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=sales_order.objects.all(),
                fields=['myOwnDefinedField', 'branch']
            )
        ]
```

I'm in a state of no idea how to achieve this. Using Django 3.1.5.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model's `save` method you can perform a query to get the greatest value in the field for the current branch, add 1 to this value and then save that as the new value. Only do this if there is not already a value so that we don't overwrite existing rows

Use [Meta.unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to enforce this constraint at the DB level too

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_unique_id = models.IntegerField(editable=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('branch', 'branch_unique_id'),
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.branch_unique_id:
            self.branch_unique_id = SalesOrder.objects.filter(
                branch=self.branch
            ).aggregate(
                max=Coalesce(models.Max('branch_unique_id'), 0)
            )['max'] + 1
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm unaware of  Coalesce, will have to look at this and also the logic used here, will reply back once I understand. Anyways thanks for the input.

Comment: @RanuVijay If there are no existing rows for that branch the max will be `None`, Coalesce just turns that `None` into a `0` so that you can add `1` to it, if the first argument passed to it is null then it returns the second

Comment: hey, can you explain this - Only do this if there is not already a value so that we don't overwrite existing rows.. do you mean the update part?

Comment: @RanuVijay if the SalesOrder we are saving already has a branch_unique_id then there is no need to calculate a new one. We may be saving an existing record to update some other field